# (Please Answer.. plssss.. ) If our dua can get unanswered then what is the point in making dua in the first place?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, dua, atheists

I went through this antireligious talk of George Carlin where he says that whatever god you believe and to whomever you pray to, there is only 50-50 chance that your prayer gets answered. And he also says that if one can agree that his prayer got unanswered because God willed something better for him, then what is the point in making that prayer in the first place?

Link to the video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8r-e2NDSTuE

I did went through some of the answers already published but I was not satisfied with the explanations written there. So first I apologize for posing another question under the same topic. Hope my doubt may get clarified here.

Let's consider that we did one dua based on the Islamic rulings and within the islamic criteria. Even if that dua is not good for our future (we usually don't know about it). If that dua get unanswered i.e, won't happen the way we wished then what is the point in asking that dua?

For example, 
If I were to make a dua that: Oh Allah! Bless me with a baby boy who will strive hard for your cause and who will also work for the upliftement of our society?

And if I were to be blessed with a baby girl. Then as a Muslim we know that this is what Allah intented and from this baby girl Allah may make happen of what I wished. And since it was Allah intention, there could have been any issues if I was blessed with a baby boy and to avoid it he may have blessed me with a baby girl.

But even if that's the case, then what is the point in making that dua? Isn't it better to just have faith that Allah's divine plan is far better than ours and just go with the flow instead of asking dua?

I do know that there is nothing wrong in what I wished. But I do know that it's compulsory to make supplication to Allah for our needs. Please do know that when I meant unanswered I meant the wish didn't happened directly, and I do know that our duas are usually answered either by happening it late or by giving us some deeds for the Hereafter or else by saving us from bad incident.

So this always comes in my mind as to why do I need to ask duas?

Or did I missed something important to know?

JAZAKALLAH!

Comment: In simple dua can be answered or it won’t but just because it is unanswered does not mean it goes unrecognised. You can be rewarded for your good deeds.

Answer (score 1):

To seek Allah's pleasure, as Dua is also a form of worship.

> إن الدعاء هو العبادة ثم قرأ: وقال ربكم ادعوني أستجب لكم إن الذين يستكبرون عن عبادتي سيدخلون جهنم داخرين
>
> Supplication is worship. Then he recited: And Your Lord said: Call upon me, I will respond to you. Verily, those who scorn My worship, they will surely enter Hell humiliated. ([40:60](https://quran.com/40/60))
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/3)</sup>

> ليس شيء أكرم على الله من الدعاء
>
> There is nothing more honorable with Allah [Most High] than supplication.
>
> <sup>— [Bulugh al-Maram](https://sunnah.com/urn/2118690)</sup>

And even if it is not directly fulfilled, it brings good.

> ما من أحد يدعو بدعاء إلا آتاه الله ما سأل أو كف عنه من السوء مثله
>
> There is none who utters a supplication, except that Allah gives him what he asked, or prevents evil from him that is equal to it.
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/12)</sup>